# How to get script to create a new file that lists folder content sorted by size

Tags: bash, unix

I have a script that sorts and processes unsorted files to newly created directories.

Its working great, but I am trying to understand the leanest method to get the script to create an additional file within each newly created directory that:

1.Contains a list of all files in the directory sorted by size order.

2.Outputs a further file to the desktop that contains a label for each directory and lists the files sorted in reverse alphabetical order.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Good Morning, Please enter your file type name for sorting [ENTER]:" all_extensions
if cd /Users/christopherdorman/desktop
  then  while read extension
      do    destination="folder$extension"
        mkdir -p "$destination"
        mv  -v unsorted/*."$extension" "$destination"
      done   <<< "${all_extensions// /$'\n'}"
        mkdir -p foldermisc 
        if mv  -v unsorted/* "foldermisc"
      then  echo "Good News, the rest of Your files have been successfully processed"
        fi
fi
```

Comment: This might help as first step (with GNU find and GNU sort): `find /path/to/directory -maxdepth 1 -printf "%s;%f" -print0 | sort -z -t ";" -n -k1,1 | tr '\0' '\n'`

Comment: where is this put in the code block

Comment: could this be done coding in a touch tempfile with some sort of ls -lhs nested